# Relaying Signals/Slots With Meta Data Types

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

It compiles fine, but this is the error message I am when I run my program:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<double>'
(Make sure 'QVector<double>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

The first part was running fine, it's when I added another layer (in other words the relay) that I got this new error message. So this is the part which worked:

```
connect(&m_dataTestTab, SIGNAL(notifyAddGraph()),
                &m_dataTest, SLOT(createGraph()));

connect(&m_dataTest, SIGNAL(sendGraphData(QVector<double>,QVector<double>)),
                &m_dataTestTab, SLOT(drawGraph(QVector<double>,QVector<double>)));
```

At this point the setup was as such:

```
Press a button -> create some data -> emit data back to the view and draw graph
```

I decided I wanted that `sendGraphData` above to work on a thread, so inside the `dataTest` class, I added this extra layer, where the `worker` class is on it's own thread so the setup would now be:

```
Press a button -> notifies DataTest to launch a thread -> emit data from thread -> relay data from DataTest to the view -> draw my graph in the view
```

So the extra layer inside `DataTest` has this connect:

```
connect(m_worker, SIGNAL(sendGraphData(QVector<double>,QVector<double>)),
                this, SLOT(relaySendGraphData(QVector<double>,QVector<double>)));
```

Then for the `relaySendGraphData`:

```
void DataTest::relaySendGraphData(const QVector<double> &valueX, const QVector<double> &valueY)
    {
        qDebug() << valueX;
        emit sendGraphData(valueX, valueY); //should now connect up to the view
    }
```

This should have effectively emitted data from the thread (`worker`), to the `DataTest` class then relayed this to the `DataTestTab` (or the view) so it didn't have to know anything about the thread.

It doesn't even enter the `relaySendGraphData` and if I remove that extra layer of connect, then the error message goes away.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: as your `connect` tells you, you need to register `QVector<double>` to the `MetaObjectSystem`, afaik just what @Chernobyl posted

Comment: so I add his line to my constructor?

Comment: Added it to my constructor and it worked, will also try the namespace =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
qRegisterMetaType<QVector<double> >("QVector<double>");
```

Compiles fine because error with signals and slots usually can be detected at runtime.

Doc: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType

So you can try this:

```
typedef QVector<double> MyArray;
// ... 
qRegisterMetaType<MyArray>("MyArray");
// ... 
connect(this, SIGNAL(signal(MyArray)),this, SLOT(slot(MyArray)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Comment: Where should I put this - in the `worker` threaded class and why?

Should I put it in the signal/slots part @Chernobyl

Comment: Also how come my signal and slots were working with QVectors before and not with this extra layer?